# How do I manage mutiple projects in a single Laravel framework folder?

Tags: php, laravel

First of all, I'm not a native English speaker so please understand some clumsy expressions I may use if there any :)

---

I just started some days ago with this excellent framework, and now I want to use it for many projects our company is running at the moment.

It doesn't seem that hard to manage just a single project with Laravel since I don't really have to care much about sub-folders, namespaces, and etc.

When it comes to multiple projects, however, I can't get how I can seperate controllers and models for each projects

To be more specifically speaking,

How can I make controllers & model work when they are in the sub folders?

For instance,

```
Route::post('entries','entries@create');
```

the  above one runs fine, since "entries.php" file is located at "controllers" folder, but what if the controller "entries.php" is in a sub-folder?

how can I specify the path of the sub-folder-located file so that a code at the above automatically finds it?

The same question goes with the case of models too.

Comment: I think you should look into [bundles](http://laravel.com/docs/bundles).

Comment: @ Joseph Silbet Thanks for the suggestion :) I haven't looked at Bundles yet :)

Answer (score 3):

Within routes.php

```
Route::post('entries','folder.entries@create');
```

The "entries" controller file within the "folder" folder.

```
class Folder_Entries_Controller extends Base_Controller {

public function action_index()
{
    // Code Here
}

}
```